# Error accessing R resource after moving project

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-resources, user-permissions

I have incomplete project source files. I filled a newly created project with these. But now I can't access the R.string resource.
By the way; I would like to point out that I have also tried all the solutions listed on the https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-fix-cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio/ website.

I am getting the following errors.

[image: Errors]

error: cannot find symbol

Toast.makeText(this, R.string.permission_audio, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

^
symbol: variable permission_audio
location: class string

```
protected void checkPermissionResult(final int requestCode, final String permission, final boolean result) {
        // show Toast when there is no permission
        if (Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO.equals(permission)) {
            onUpdateAudioPermission(result);
            if (!result) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.permission_audio, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        if (Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.equals(permission)) {
            onUpdateExternalStoragePermission(result);
            if (!result) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.permission_ext_storage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        if (Manifest.permission.INTERNET.equals(permission)) {
            onUpdateNetworkPermission(result);
            if (!result) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.permission_network, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

protected boolean checkPermissionWriteExternalStorage() {
        if (!PermissionCheck.hasWriteExternalStorage(this)) {
            MessageDialogFragment.showDialog(this, REQUEST_PERMISSION_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    R.string.permission_title, R.string.permission_ext_storage_request,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE});
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

protected boolean checkPermissionAudio() {
        if (!PermissionCheck.hasAudio(this)) {
            MessageDialogFragment.showDialog(this, REQUEST_PERMISSION_AUDIO_RECORDING,
                    R.string.permission_title, R.string.permission_audio_recording_request,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO});
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
```

Strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">ScreenRecordingSample</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: did you copy the res folder as well?

Comment: I copied and pasted the src/main part completely :)

Comment: Because strings.xml has no matching texts to R.string.xxxxxx values.

Comment: Android ide says: "Do you want to trust this project?". I had to copy paste too. Frankly, I couldn't trust the project. Where does the R.string come from? Is this resource generated from strings.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you maybe lack the basic understanding of what `R` actually is. It basically is the way to refer to anything in your `res` folder. If you don't have a string called `permission_audio` you also can't use it. All these `R.string` values are values you need to define yourself, inside the project, in the res folder.

Strings are typically defined inside `res\values\strings.xml`

Inside you will find something like

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">App name</string>
</resources>
```

Here all other strings also need to be defined, so if you change it to

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">App name</string>
    <string name="permission_audio">Text for showing permission audio</string>
</resources>
```

you will notice that `R.string.permission_audio` won't give an error anymore

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. As I guessed, it looks for the values in strings.xml. But the original github version of the project does not have strings.xml values either. https://github.com/saki4510t/ScreenRecordingSample/blob/master/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml

Comment: Worked. I wrote irrelevant texts. Why is strings.xml empty in github file? This confused me. Because I thought they would put a working file. In the original github project, is strings.xml being populated from different sources while the project is being compiled? Is this possible ? Because the original strings.xml file is empty. https://github.com/saki4510t/ScreenRecordingSample/blob/master/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml

Comment: @Pınar no idea why they are empty. that's a bit strange yeah. I guess only the developer of that project knows

Answer (score 1):

Just Import below Resource file in your Activity

```
import **com.*yourPackageName*.R**;
```

if your activity in some Folder so add folder name in Import statement.

```
import **com.yourPackageName.*FolderName*.R**;
```

Comment: I've tried. It said "Unused import statement" and stays inactive (greyed out).